# Deep Learning using Weka GUI and deeplearning4j

Tags: deep-learning

I am looking for documentation on how to run deep learning using the Weka GUI.
I downloaded the deeplearning4j package and tried to run the examples.

The 3 examples say
"The following explains how to build a neural network from the command line, programmatically in java and in the Weka workbench GUI."
But if I scroll through there is no section for GUI.
So I just looked around the GUI found the algorithm in the classifiers section and tried to run it. The algorithm says it's been building the model on training data for 2 days now. I'm using the iris dataset(150 points) should it take this long?

**The dataset I eventually want to use contains 2.8million rows by 85 columns.** This is network logs of cyber attacks, with most data points being benign. **I want to run a Deep Learning algorithm and a SVM and compare the results.** I don't know If I'll be able to load this much data into weka. I could reduce the columns down to 20 but the rows will still be around 2.8 million. **I have 4-7 days to do this.(I could reduce my set to 150,000 rows and 20 columns to run within time)** Is Weka the wrong tool to use. Should I switch to Matlab GUI or Keras in python. I am a complete novice to machine learning having only used Weka to run an SVM once before for another project. I thought the Weka GUI would be a good choice since I am a beginner.

Please provide links to tutorials that show how to use the Weka GUI for deep learning or advise another beginner friendly method to run a deep net.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check this link: https://deeplearning.cms.waikato.ac.nz/install/
2. 5-7 days for the task your described does not look realistic.
3. Using Weka with the buildin Iris dataset and this classifier config:  'weka.classifiers.functions.MultilayerPerceptron -L 0.3 -M 0.2 -N 500 -V 0 -S 0 -E 20 -H a' runs in less than 1 second (RAM = 12GB, Intel Xeon, X5650 @ 2.67GHz) with the following brief result:

   Correctly Classified Instances         146                   97.3333 %

   === Confusion Matrix ===

   a  b  c       <-- classified as

   50  0  0 |  a = Iris-setosa

   0 48  2 |  b = Iris-versicolor

   0  2 48 |  c = Iris-virginica